# Right skewed distribution of a continuous variable with outliers: replace outliers with mode or median of that column?

Tags: python, data-visualization, data-transformation, pandas, data-preprocessing

When I replace my outliers with the median value of that column/feature, my mode for that column/feature also changes. Is that correct?

Comment: I suggest you windsorize or trim based on a quantile, e. g. 10%. However, it is important to investigate why these values were generated in the first place.

Comment: @00schneider means winsorize. I agree that’s much, much better than replacing outliers with the median, but why replace them at all?

Comment: @00schneider thank you..so u mean to say that i should trim the top and bottom 10% of the tails? It is usually said that median is the best way to replace the outliers. How is trimming top and bottom 10% a better approach? or is it a special case with right skewed distributions?.. as in trimming is better than replacing with median when it comes to right skewed distributions?

Comment: I think you are confusing the treatment of outliers with the treatment of missing data. I recommend the literature of Wilcox for an introduction of the idea behind winsorizing/trimming.